# Why am I getting "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" when not modifying the enumerated collection?

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration

I have two collections of strings: CollectionA is a StringCollection property of an object stored in the system, while CollectionB is a List generated at runtime. CollectionA needs to be updated to match CollectionB if there are any differences. So I devised what I expected to be a simple LINQ method to perform the removal.

```
var strDifferences = CollectionA.Where(foo => !CollectionB.Contains(foo));
foreach (var strVar in strDifferences) { CollectionA.Remove(strVar); }
```

But I am getting a `"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"` error on strDifferences... even though it is a separate enumerable from the collection being modified! I originally devised this *explicitly* to evade this error, as my first implementation would produce it (as I was enumerating across `CollectionA` and just removing when `!CollectionB.Contains(str)`). Can anyone shed some insight into why this enumeration is failing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The two are not completely separate. `Where` does not make a separate copy of the collection. It internally keeps a reference to the original collection and fetches elements from it as you request them.

You can solve your problem by adding `ToList()` to force `Where` to iterate through the collection immediately.

```
var strDifferences = CollectionA
    .Where(foo => !CollectionB.Contains(foo))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ToArray()` be better here? There is no need to use `List`.

Comment: @svick That's something I've wondered about for quite some time, but that'd be a question I'd ask on another day. Provided it hasn't already been asked, of course -chuckle-

Comment: @GraceNote catch that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105990/is-it-better-to-call-tolist-or-toarray-in-linq-queries

Answer (score 4):

`Where` passes back `IEnumerable<T>` and then you are using that in your `foreach (var strVar in strDifferences)`

You are then trying to remove it from the collection that created the `IEnumerable<T>`.  You haven't created a new list, it's referencing `CollectionA` to pull the next item from, so you can't edit `CollectionA`.

You can do this also:

```
var strDifferences = CollectionA.Where
  (foo => CollectionB.Contains(foo)).ToList();

CollectionA = strDifferences;
//or instead of reassigning CollectionA
CollectionA.Clear();
CollectionA.AddRange(strDifferences);
```

Since you are removing the ones that aren't in CollectionB.  Just look for the ones that are, create a list and assign that list to the CollectionA variable.

Comment: Ah... I'd love to use your alternative (however identical in effect it is), but unfortunately CollectionA, it turns out, is a read-only property, so I can't set it. You do give a much more in-depth explanation, though, so +1 for that.

Comment: @ccornet if can't set it you could clear it and add the items back in.

Comment: I thought about it long and hard. I decided to still go with the removal approach. I don't wish to modify CollectionA if no change is necessary, building a list of what needs to be removed makes this very quick and simple to know (just see if strDifferences.Count > 0). If I build an array of the goal, I'd still have to check if CollectionA has something that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying the first line a bit:

```
var strDifferences =
    CollectionA.Where(foo => !CollectionB.Contains(foo)).ToList();
```

I think LINQ is using lazy execution of your query. The call to `ToList` will force execution of the query prior to enumerating.

Comment: Yes, and make sure not to put it over two lines i..e.       
var strDifferencesTemp =
    CollectionA.Where(foo => !CollectionB.Contains(foo));     
var strDifferences = strDifferencesTemp.ToList();                    
                               
if you do so, the collection can be modified by some other thread between these two lines.

Comment: @Markus if multi-threading, it doesn't make any difference even you put it in one line. You'd better consider immutablelist in that case.