# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#

I have this code that removes a player if the player is not alive, but I figured the problem is to do with the `foreach` loop. I've seen solutions involving making new lists, but I cannot see how I can apply it to my code. Can anyone please shed some light?

```
private Dictionary<int, Player> numPlayers = new Dictionary<int, Player>();

private void CheckPlayers()
{
    foreach (Player player in numPlayers.Values)
    {
        if (!player.isAlive)
        {
            canvas.Children.Remove(player.hand);
            numPlayers.Remove(player.id); // breaks here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" when not modifying the enumerated collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791503/why-am-i-getting-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query the collection for the players to delete:

```
var playersToDelete = numPlayers.Values.Where(p => !p.isAlive).ToList();
```

Then delete the players:

```
foreach(var player in playersToDelete) {
    canvas.Children.Remove(player.hand);
    numPlayers.Remove(player.id);
}
```

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to resolve Where - I'm not sure which reference I might be missing?

Comment: You need a using for `System.Linq`. I imagine you already have the reference to `System.Core`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify the collection you are iterating over with `foreach`.  What you need to do is add the items you want to remove to a new list, then once that list is built remove them.

```
var dead = numPlayers.Values
    .Where(p => !p.isAlive)
    .ToList();

foreach(var player in dead)
{
    canvas.Children.Remove(player.hand);
    numPlayer.Remove(player.id);
}
```

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to resolve `Where` - I'm not sure which reference I might be missing?

Comment: you need a `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the elements of a collection using a reverse for:

```
for(int i = numPlayers.Values.Count - 1; i <= 0; i--)
{
//Remove it.
}
```