# Retrieve All Children From Parent[]

Tags: c#, linq

Given this class:

```
public class Parent
{
  public Child[] Children {get;set;}
}
```

And this array:

```
Parent[] parents;
```

How can I retrieve *all* the children from the parents array using Linq or something else? This seems bad:

```
IList<Child> children = new List<Child>();
foreach(var parent in parents)
  children.AddRange(parent.Children);
```

Or is that not so bad? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).ToArray()
```

Comment: Bingo Bango, SelectMany is one of the handi-dandiest parts of linq.

Comment: He wants a List though. You'll need to have a List.AddRange(parents.SelectMany...)

Comment: @Joel Etherton: or just .ToList() instead of .ToArray() :)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: ToList is way more time consuming, thats why I prefere ToArray

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I just want to revert what I have said. I learned it better and i like to share this. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105990/is-it-better-to-call-tolist-or-toarray-in-linq-queries So it's better to profile things before assuming a situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the solution you propose in the question is bad. It is very readable and easy to understand what is going on. Unless you have some reason you need to optimize this, I don't see any fault with it.

If you just really want to use Linq, that's another story (and in my opinion perfectly valid -- the more experience/practice with Linq, the better)