# Efficiency of ToList()

Tags: c#, .net

A lot of the developers I work with feel more comfortable working with a `List` as opposed to `IEnumerable` (for example).  I am wondering whether there is any performance impact for `ToList()` overuse. For example, or, will use `ToList()` after ordering to get a list back out again i.e.

```
private void ListThinger(List<T> input)
{
  input = input.OrderBy(s => s.Thing).ToList();
  foreach(var thing in input)
  {
      // do things
  }
}
```

My question is:

- How efficient is the `ToList()` method? Will it create a new list and how much memory does that take, assuming the contents are POCOs? Does this change if its a value type rather than a POCO?
- Will the size of the list determine efficiency or does size of list not determine cost of `ToList()`?
- If a list is cast to an `IEnumerable` and then `ToList()` is called on it, will it just return the original object?

P.s. I understand that a single use of ToList won't break any backs, but we are building a highly concurrent system that is currently CPU bound so I am looking for little wins that, when scaled, will add up to a big improvement

Comment: As documentation says it **Creates** a `List<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`. So question 1p2 and 3 are already answered (your first question is actually 4 questions, which should be split apart)

Comment: In your specific example, the `ToList` should be removed since it adds no value (since all you do is iterate over it a single time).

Comment: `If a list is cast to an IEnumerable and then ToList() is called on it, will it just return the original object?` No.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a performance impact when calling ToList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15516462/69809).

Comment: Any reason you can't test this stuff yourself?

Comment: `ToList()` is very efficient. Calling it when you don't need to is inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

> How efficient is the ToList() method? Will it create a new list and how much memory does that take, assuming the contents are POCOs? Does this change if its a value type rather than a POCO?

The `ToList()` method materializes the given collection by creating a new list and populating it with the items of the given collection. [`Linq.ToList()` implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,26e88ad0515fb01e):

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

By doing so you are not gaining the power of deffered execution if needed

---

> Will the size of the list determine efficiency or does size of list not determine cost of ToList()?

As it calls `List`s copy constructor and it creates a new list then it'll work on each of the items. So it'll run in `O(n)` - meaning that list's size matters. MSDNs documentation about the operation of the copy constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the List class that contains elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.

As @Jason mentioned in the comment bellow the Copy Constructor is smart and is efficient but doing it when not needed is still an `O(n)` operation that doesn't have to happen

---

> If a list is cast to an IEnumerable and then ToList() is called on it, will it just return the original object?

No. It will create a new list as seen above

---

As for your example code:

```
input = input.OrderBy(s => s.Thing).ToList();
foreach(var thing in input)
{
   // do things
}
```

As you are getting a materialized list (rather than an `IQueriable`/`IEnumerable` that might perform in deffered execution) adding the `ToList` after the adding gives you no benefit.

You can look here, might also help: [When to use LINQ's .ToList() or .ToArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12014969/6400526)

Comment: May at least be worth noting that in the constructor, it tries to be somewhat efficient by using the `Array.CopyTo` if it can cast to `ICollection<T>`, which while still O(n), it is more efficient than you can do yourself since it uses unmanaged internal `Copy` method.

Comment: Not as efficient as the new `ToArray` stuff in .NET core that creates a linked list of buffers, instead of doing copy-resize whenever the internal array runs out. It does a full iteration capturing all elements in a cluster of buffers, then copies them all into the final array at the end.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth and with `OrderBy` if the source is fixed-length then it doesn't even need that linked list as it knows the size to begin with, (an efficiency also used with `ToList()` in such cases) but even the most efficient `ToList()` is going to be less efficient than not doing one when it gains nothing.

Comment: @Chris - Did this help you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes is creates a new list. It is hard to accurately measure the memory usage but it is likely to be class size + (system word size * element count). I recommend a memory profiler.
2. Algorithmic efficiency of operations will of course be impacted by the element count
3. Yes, you get a brand new list every time. References inside are *not* duplicated but primitives are.

Try it yourself:

```
var list = new List<int>();
bool areListsTheSame = list == ((IEnumerable<int>)list).ToList();
```