# Search for any word in a Linq query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm passing a string to a controller, and need the controller to search for ANY of the words passed, within the Title field of my database.

eg. id="outlook error message"

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Lookup(string id)
    {
        List<string> listOfSearch = id.Split(' ').ToList();
        var results = db.KS.Where(x => x.Title.Intersect(listOfSearch).Any());
```

This produces the following two errors:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'string' to '`System.Linq.IQueryable<string>`
>
> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Intersect' and the best extension method overload '`System.Linq.Queryable.Intersect<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)`' has some invalid arguments

Can anyone please advise what's wrong, or how to populate results with just a list of Titles that contain any of the words passed in?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: I had a similar question not long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215100/linq-to-entities-orderby-statement-involving-extension-method (it has an answer to the problem you're having)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = db.KS.Where(x => listOfSearch.Any(item => x.Title.Contains(item)));
```

**Update**:
For LinqToSql:

```
var titles = db.KS.Select(item => item.Title)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(title => listOfSearch.Any(word => title.Contains(word)));
```

Comment: Hi - this looks like it would work - but if I pass in "outlook err..." it will only return items where it has "outlook err.." specifically, not "outlook" or "error" - do you know how to achieve that please?  Thank you, Mark

Comment: Sorry my mistake - it does work - it's the Twitter TypeAhead which is only hilighting entries where all text appears.  That's another question though :)  Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
 List<string> listOfSearch = id.Split(' ').ToList();
 var result = from item in db.KS
              where listOfSearch.Any(v => item.Title.Contains(v)) 
              select item;
```

or

```
var result = db.KS.Where(item => listOfSearch.Any(v => item.Title.Contains(v)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the statement to:

```
db.KS.Intersect(....
```

KS returns you the IQueryable on which you can directly perform the intersection.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RogerRowland , Changed from rhetorical question to simple answer.

Comment: could you please give your answer a bit more substance so make it a more valueable contribution?