# Why does Enumerable<T>.ToArray() use an intermediary Buffer when it can just call Count() first?

Tags: .net, performance, linq

I was reading through a question asking [Is it better to call ToList() or ToArray() in LINQ queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105990/is-it-better-to-call-tolist-or-toarray-in-linq-queries) and found myself wondering why `Enumerable.ToArray()` wouldn't first just call the `Count()` method to find the size of the collection instead of using the internal `Buffer{T}` class which dynamically resizes itself. Something like the following:

```
T[] ToArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var array = new T[count];

    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in source) array[index++] = item;
    return array;
}
```

I know that we can't understand what is going through the minds of the designers and implementers and I'm sure they're much smarter than myself. So the best way to ask this question is what's wrong with the approach shown above? It seems to be less memory allocation and still operates in O(n) time.

Comment: Because calling `Count()` first would require enumerating the sequence twice.

Comment: Because by calling Count() and then iterating over the sequence again to get the elements would execute potential side effects twice.

Comment: @RichardDeeming not necessarily though. If the type also implements `ICollection` it is optimized to use the `Count` property directly. It still makes sense to avoid `Count()` here.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Took the words out of my mouth.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: That's a big "if". The `ToArray` method can't assume that the input sequence will implement anything other that `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming agree. There's no guarantee that it will implement `ICollection` so the safe bet is to avoid calling `Count()`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming If that were the case, then the Count() method wouldn't make the very same optimization.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Plus, if the input sequence *does* implement `ICollection<T>`, the `Buffer<T>` class uses the `Count` property to allocate an array of the correct size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `Buffer<T>` class constructor also optimizes if the specified sequence can be casted to `ICollection`(like array or list) which has a `Count` property:

```
TElement[] array = null;
int num = 0;
ICollection<TElement> collection = source as ICollection<TElement>;
if (collection != null)
{
    num = collection.Count;
    if (num > 0)
    {
        array = new TElement[num];
        collection.CopyTo(array, 0);
    }
}
else
    // now we are going the long way ...
```

So if it's not a collection the query must be executed to get the total count. But using `Enumerable.Count` just to initialize the array  correctly sized can be very expensive and - more important - could have dangerous side-effects. Hence it is unsafe.

Consider this simple [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) example:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
int count = lines.Count(); // executes the query which also disposes the underlying IO.TextReader 
var array = new string[count];
int index = 0;
foreach (string line in lines) array[index++] = line;
```

This will throw an `ObjectDisposedException` "Cannot read from a closed TextReader" since `lines.Count()` already executed the query and in the meantime  the reader is disposed at `foreach`.

Comment: Another example would be `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`. Calling `Count()` would consume the items in the collection and the iteration would then return nothing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would have voted for your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17180637/57611), it being more complete--don't delete next time!

Answer (score 4):

The `Buffer<T>` class has an optimization for the case where the source sequence implements `ICollection<T>`:

```
internal Buffer(IEnumerable<TElement> source)
{
   int length = 0;
   TElement[] array = null;
   ICollection<TElement> collection = source as ICollection<TElement>;
   if (collection != null)
   {
      length = collection.Count;
      if (length > 0)
      {
         array = new TElement[length];
         collection.CopyTo(array, 0);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      ...
```

If the sequence doesn't implement `ICollection<T>`, the code cannot assume that it's safe to enumerate the sequence twice, so it falls back to resizing the array as required.

Answer (score 1):

Because Count() enumerates the source to the end. So it will at minimum do 2 iterations, one just for the count and the other to copy the items.

Now consider that the enumerable in question is a database cursor or something else similar that involves non trivial operations when iterating. That would be a performance killer.

It's a way better idea to just memcopy and extend the buffer. It might have a slight performance impact but it's very small and more important it's a **known quantity**.

Comment: BTW, you can't “memcopy” out of `IEnumerable<T>`, you have to do it item by item.

Comment: i was referring to memcopying the buffer array when extending it. Of course that you need to get every item one by one from the enumerable

Answer (score 0):

If `IEnumerable<T>` and/or `IEnumerator<T>` had included a property to ask whether it "knew" its count, along with a `Count` property, it might have been worthwhile for `ToArray()` to make use of such a thing [having the `Count` be part of `IEnumerator<T>` would be helpful in cases where e.g. calling `GetEnumerator` on a a thread-safe mutable type will enumerate a snapshot].  Absent such ability, even if code has an `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`, there's no way for it to know whether calling `Count` will take more or less time than creating extra temporary arrays.

That having been said, I would expect that the optimal implementation for something like `ToArray` would probably be to use a linked list of things, each of which holds some number of items, so that each item would be read into the space it would occupy until such time as it can be copied to the final array.  The doubling strategy of `List<T>` doesn't seem particularly appropriate here, since it would be better to have information divided among multiple small arrays than to create an array of over 85,000 bytes (since the temporary arrays will be useless after it exits, having them end up on the Large Object Heap would be particularly bad).

Comment: “having the `Count` be part of `IEnumerator<T>` would be helpful” Isn't that exactly what `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` (and the less general `ICollection<T>`) is for?

Comment: @svick It also would remove the ability to have an infinite enumerable collection removing the stream-ability so-to-speak of an enumerable.

Comment: @svick: Calling an interface member is generally faster than trying to cast to another interface type, whether or not the cast succeeds.  Further, if type `Bunch<T>` happens to implement `IList<T>` but not the non-generic `ICollection`, there's no nice way for code which expects an `IEnumerable<Animal>` to quickly find out how many things are in a `Bunch<Cat>`.  Also, while a thread-safe collection can offer snapshot enumeration semantics, the value returned by `ICollection.Count` may have no relation to the number of items returned by a preceding or following `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: @Anthony: If `IEnumerable` had a property to say whether it knew its count, such a property could return a "flags" `enum` to indicate whether the count was known, whether it could be over two billion, whether it could be infinite, whether it was known to be infinite, whether it should be expected to never change, whether it should be expected not to change between a `Count` and an complete enumeration if the thread performing such actions doesn't explicitly mutate the underlying collection, etc.

Comment: @supercat 1. If a type doesn't implement `ICollection` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, then it most likely also wouldn't return count from `IEnumerator<T>`, even if it could. 2. If you want to have count-consistent snapshot, don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but add a method like `IReadOnlyList<T> Snaphost()`. 3. I think you're overcomplicating this (I'm especially worried about that “etc.”). You're creating an unreliable (it can always say “I don't know”) monster that will be useful in tiny minority of cases. Right now, `IEnumerator<T>` is simple and easy to implement and I like it that way.

Comment: @svick: Since `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` don't inherit from `IReadOnlyList<T>` nor `ICollection`, and since prior to the introduction of covariant interfaces there was no advantage to implementing `ICollection`, there are a lot of implementations of those types which have a `Count` method but don't implement the aforementioned interfaces.  As for the `etc`., having a method which returns a single flags enum doesn't seem overly complicated.  Define the semantics so that "0" will be a "safe" value for an enumerator that doesn't know how to do anything special and go from there.

Comment: @svick: As for suggesting that a collection implement some "other" method for taking a snap-shot, it's normal for code that wants a snapshot of an `IEnumerable<T>` to do something like `ToArray()` or `ToList()`.  It's possible for a threadsafe collection to implement `IEnumerable<T>` in such fashion that those methods work to take a snapshot; why require the use of some other method?