# Can you stack multiple IEnumerable queries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, indexing, ienumerable

Do Linq methods on IEnumerable objects stack or do they override previous methods?

For example

```
string[] exampleArray = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
IEnumerable<string> iEnum1 = exampleArray.Skip(1); 
IEnumerable<string> iEnum2 = iEnum1.Take(5); 
IEnumerable<string> iEnum3 = iEnum2.Skip(1); 
IEnumerable<string> iEnum4 = iEnum3.Take(2); 
int count = iEnum4.Count();
```

Could I expect `count` to equal 2 and could I still expect `iEnum3` to enumerate over `"3", "4", "5", "6"` if I wish to reuse that IEnumerable?

I'm trying to avoid creating new arrays even though they would be logically simpler to work with as the initial array will be relatively large already (from an even larger file stream).

Comment: You may want to take a look at the values in a debugger or print them to the console.

Comment: You could write it like this exampleArray.Skip(1).Take(5).Skip(1).Take(2).Count();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do "stack" as you put it (typically referred to as "chaining").

Those LINQ statements (Take, Skip) are extensions of IEnumerable, and the end result will be that `iEnum4` is `exampleArray.Skip(1).Take(5).Skip(1).Take(2)`

The final evaluation of that statement is deferred until certain methods are called (such as `Count`), at which time the LINQ statement is evaluated and the final result is stored in your `int count` variable.

> Could I expect count to equal 2 and could I still expect iEnum3 to enumerate over "3", "4", "5", "6" if I wish to reuse that IEnumerable?

Yes, `iEnum3` would evaluate whatever LINQ query it contained, such that `iEnum3.Count()` could evaluate to a different value than `iEnum4.Count()`. But if you call `iEnum3.Count()` three different times in your program, you might get three different results, because the evaluation is deferred and the values in `exampleArray` might have changed in the meantime.

Comment: iEnum3.Count would only change if `exampleArray` was a type collection that could change correct? 

Since `exampleArray` is an `Array` and you can not change the size of an `Array` after it is initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `count` will equal 2. Let's break it down:

```
var iEnum1 = exampleArray.Skip(1); // { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }
var iEnum2 = iEnum1.Take(5);       // { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" }
var iEnum3 = iEnum2.Skip(1);       // { "3", "4", "5", "6" }
var iEnum4 = iEnum3.Take(2);       // { "3", "4" }
int count = iEnum4.Count();        // 2
```

And of course, you can chain these together like this:

```
int count = exampleArray.Skip(1).Take(5).Skip(1).Take(2).Count()
```

It's important to note, however, that Linq queries are [lazy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). Meaning they aren't actually evaluated until you iterate over the result set. The comments above only indicate what the variable *would* be, if you inspected the result set, but Linq doesn't *actually* produce that result until it needs it (for example, when you call `Count`). So while you can reuse `iEnum3` in other Linq queries, it probably won't have any performance benefit—though it might promote code reuse / readability.

Comment: So you have to use ToArray after the take on line 4 if you want to cache iEnum3 without a perf hit every time you enumerate it.

Comment: @csaam You'd have to do it after the `Skip` on line 3. You could also use `ToList` (which is very slightly faster).

Comment: Yes I mixed my variables in my head my bad.  I was not aware ToList was faster.  To you have a reference on that I'm curious.

Comment: @csaam see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105990/is-it-better-to-call-tolist-or-toarray-in-linq-queries