# populating list of objects in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a linq to sql which creates a list of object

```
List<Student> Student= playerpoints.AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(r => new { Name = r.Field<string>("ID"), Action = r.Field<string>("Name") })
                      .Select(grp => new Student
                      {

                          AwardName = grp.Key.Action,
                          Count = grp.Count()

                      }).ToList();
```

and i am converting it into list of objects using snippet in this method

```
Student[] objects = list.ConvertAll<Student>(item => (Student)item).ToArray();
```

Is there a way i can directly do this?

I mean instead of converting to list and then to a object array can i directly populate the array of objects instead of the list of object??

Comment: Can't you assign directly instead of assigning to a list in the first statement?

Comment: In 12 years as a c# developer I have never used `ConvertAll` I think it is not exactly deprecated but there is really no reason to ever use it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can call `ToArray()` instead of `ToList()`. In order to become an array the query will execute exactly the same.

I should note that for many cases `ToList` [can be slightly more preformant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16323412/5056), and in a very few cases significantly more preformant.

You are likely returning this from a method though, in this method signature I *strongly* encourage the return value to be `IEnumerable<Student>` or `ImmutableList<Student>` (in the latter case you call `.ToImmutableList()`). Returning a `List`, an `IList`, or even to a lesser extent an array implies that you expect users to modify that collection, whereas the two I recommend do not. So long as your query has evaluated before you return there are no negatives to doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Call `ToArray` instead of `ToList`

```
Student[] objects = playerpoints.AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(r => new { Name = r.Field<string>("ID"), Action = r.Field<string>("Name") })
                      .Select(grp => new Student
                      {

                          AwardName = grp.Key.Action,
                          Count = grp.Count()

                      }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

directly you can return array

```
string[] Student= playerpoints.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(r => new { Name = r.Field<string>("ID"), Action = r.Field<string>("Name") })
                  .Select(grp => new Student
                  {

                      AwardName = grp.Key.Action,
                      Count = grp.Count()

                  }).ToArray();
```