# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. why?

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

Sorry, I searched about this error but it's a different case and it doesn't help me...

I want to make a Spaceship Invasion Game and i made a list of all bullets as PicutreBox.

```
List<PictureBox> all_bullets = new List<PictureBox>();
```

When you press the Space button(fire button) a new bullet is created, added in the form control's and in the list **all_bullets**.

When the buttle goes from the form `if (_bullet.Location.Y <= 0)` the _bullet from this code(below) should be removed from the `all_bullets` list.

```
private void tmr_bullets_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (PictureBox _bullet in all_bullets)
        {
            _bullet.Location = new Point(_bullet.Location.X, _bullet.Location.Y - 20);

            if (_bullet.Location.Y <= 0)
            {  all_bullets.Remove(_bullet);  }
        }

        nr_bullets.Text = Convert.ToString(all_bullets.Count);
```

Error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Sorry if it's re-posted but i didn't found what i need.

Comment: You try to remove an element in your `all_bullets` _while_ you iterating it.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not modify the collection while you are enumerating on it

```
all_bullets.Remove(_bullet);
```

this will modify (delete an item from collection) while you are enumerating on it

you can use a hack to do this

```
foreach (PictureBox _bullet in all_bullets.ToList())
```

Comment: For your hack, `ToArray()` will work just as well, while being a little lighter on resources...

Comment: it will work but [it is not better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16323412/3970411), the resource usage difference can be ignored. @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: Thanks for the link, @dotctor. I didn't think about the final reallocation required when using `ToArray()`.