# “Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute” inside System.Data.TypedTableBase<>

Tags: c#, datatable, datarowcollection

I have an .NET 4.0 assembly; it is registered in GAC and works as part of a BizTalk “orchestration”. 
Sometimes I get the following error  - “Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute. : System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.”. I cannot reproduce it; when I run the same processing of the same data, my assembly does not generate the error in this place.

The error happens when I call ‘.Where().ToArray()’ for a datatable object: an object of classd System.Data.TypedTableBase.

Here is the code:
..................

```
int? setTypeGroupId;
...

return instances.WorkContributors.Where
    (
        c =>
            !c.IsInterestedPartyNoNull()
            && c.InterestedPartyNo == publisherIpNo
            && c.SetTypeNo == 1
            && (c.RecordType == "SPU")
        && c.TypeCode == "E" 
            && (!setTypeGroupId.HasValue ||  
            (setTypeGroupId.HasValue && c.SetTypeGroupID == setTypeGroupId))
    ).ToArray();
..................
```

The object ‘instances’ is a dataset – my class produced from System.Data.DataSet.
The property ‘instances.WorkContributors’ is a datatable: an object of class System.Data.TypedTableBase.
The class MyDataRowClass  is produced from System.Data.DataRow.

The call stack after the error was the following:
Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute. : System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
at System.Data.RBTree`1.RBTreeEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__97`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at MyProduct.FileParser.Types.CWR.PWRType.GetPublishers(CWRWorkInstances instances, Nullable`1 setTypeGroupId)
at MyProduct.FileParser.Validation.Concreate.PwrTypeValidation.ValidatePublisherNumber()
at MyProduct.FileParser.Validation.Concreate.PwrTypeValidation.Validate()
at MyProduct.FileParser.Types.CWR.PWRType.StoreRecord(CWRWorkInstances workInstances, CWRWorkParsingContext context)
at MyProduct.FileParser.Groups.CWR.NWRGroup.StoreGroup(Int32 workBatchID, CWRFileCommonData commonData)
at MyProduct.FileParser.CWRParser.ProcessCWRFile(String fileName, Boolean wait, Boolean deleteFile, String sourceFileName)

I cannot understand why the error happens; and why it happens only sometimes and does not happen on the same processed data again.
The error “Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.” Itself is pretty straightforward for me; but I do not see why it happens in that my code.  The error is excepted if a code like this:

```
foreach (DataRow currRow in _someDataTable.Rows)
{
    if (/*deletion condition*/)
    {
        someDataTable.Rows.Remove(currRow);
    }
}
```

But my code above just wants to enumerate System.Data.TypedTableBase and convert the result into an array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change .ToArray() to .ToList(). There's a semantic difference between the two, best illustrated by [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41246500/3229030)

> A couple of other (good) answers have concentrated on microscopic
>   performance differences that will occur. This post is just a
>   supplement to mention the semantic difference that exists between the
>   IEnumerator produced by an array (T[]) as compared to that returned
>   by a List. Best illustrated with by example:

```
 IList<int> source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();  // try changing to .ToList()

 foreach (var x in source) {   if (x == 5)
    source[8] *= 100;   Console.WriteLine(x); } 
The above code will run with no exception and produces the output: 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
900 
10
```

> This shows that the IEnumarator returned by an int[] does not
>   keep track on whether the array has been modified since the creation
>   of the enumerator. Note that I declared the local variable source as
>   an IList. In that way I make sure the C# compiler does not
>   optimze the foreach statement into something which is equivalent to a
>   for (var idx = 0; idx < source.Length; idx++) { /* ... */ } loop. This
>   is something the C# compiler might do if I use var source = ...;
>   instead. In my current version of the .NET framework the actual
>   enumerator used here is a non-public reference-type
>   System.SZArrayHelper+SZGenericArrayEnumerator`1[System.Int32] but of
>   course this is an implementation detail. Now, if I change .ToArray()
>   into .ToList(), I get only: 1 2 3 4 5 followed by a
>   System.InvalidOperationException blow-up saying: Collection was
>   modified; enumeration operation may not execute. The underlying
>   enumerator in this case is the public mutable value-type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[System.Int32] (boxed
>   inside an IEnumerator box in this case because I use IList).
>   In conclusion, the enumerator produced by a List keeps track on
>   whether the list changes during enumeration, while the enumerator
>   produced by T[] does not. So consider this difference when choosing
>   between .ToList() and .ToArray(). People often add one extra
>   .ToArray() or .ToList() to circumvent a collection that keeps track on
>   whether it was modified during the life-time of an enumerator. (If
>   anybody wants to know how the List<> keeps track on whether collection
>   was modified, there is a private field _version in this class which is
>   changed everytime the List<> is updated.)

Comment: As I understand, after I  change "ToArray() to .ToList()", the error should become "stably reproducible"; that's the essence of you suggestion?

Comment: Right. If you're making changes to the IEnumerable, ToList'll let you know. That should help you get to the core of the problem.

Comment: But in this case some other thread should be involved - a thread that "making changes to the IEnumerable", agree? Who else can "make changes to the IEnumerable" while my thread is calling the  .ToArray()  ?

Comment: I don’t know your code, so I can’t answer that question. But one of the best troubleshooting steps I know is to check my assumptions. You might not think that any code is modifying your Enumerable but, if that was true, you wouldn’t be getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a collection while using foreach to iterate through it.
Make a copy and delete from copy.

```
 DataTable Junk = new DataTable();
 foreach (DataRow currRow in _someDataTable.Rows)
 {
     if (/*deletion condition*/)
     {
         Junk.Add(currRow);
     }
 }
 foreach (DataRow row in Junk)
 {
    _ someDataTable.Rows.REmove(row);
 }
```

Comment: "you can't modify a collection while using foreach to iterate through it. " - correct; but my code does NOT modify the collection, this is the problem. My code above just enumerates the collection 'instances.WorkContributors' (using .Where, i.e. using filtering); and then converts the result into array.

Comment: I see, can you please format your code like the one in your "theoretical example" :)

Comment: Where iterates through a collection by using ForEach I believe