# ICollection as argument: Provide List or Array

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable, icollection

If some method requires an `ICollection<T>` as an argument, but I have only an `IEnumerable<T>` available:  Is it better to convert this `IEnumerable<T>` to a `IList<T>` or is it better to convert it to an array `T[]` or shall I convert it to something else or is there no difference at all?

The `IEnumerable<T>` is only required for this method call, so no further read/write/extend is required.

Comment: A fundamental difference is that `ICollection` allows adding and removing elements while `IEnumerable` does not. So yes, you will have to persist the enumerable as a concrete collection of some sort.

Comment: I am aware of this difference, but I do not know, if it is better to convert it to `T[]` instead of `IList<T>` or the other way around.

Comment: in your case, i think it does not matter which one you choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to be accessing the elements, you should use `ToList()` as explained why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16323412/11272124).

If you'll be iterating through the elements, then it'd be better performance-wise to do it via an index (meaning casting them to an array), so that you can use a `for loop`, instead of a `foreach loop`.

`for` is faster than your typical `foreach` due to it using an index to access each element.

Comment: Great, thank you for this link, that was, what I was searching for!