# Why ToArray performance has such behavior, .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

### I attached memory tests

### I edited question

I benchmark `ToArray` and `ToList` method on `IEnumerable<int>`, and I looked pit from 530 to 800 thousand on the graphic.
I pinned my benchmark code:

```cs
 [MarkdownExporter, AsciiDocExporter, HtmlExporter, CsvExporter, RPlotExporter, PlainExporter] [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class IntBenchmarks
    {
        private IEnumerable<int> EnumerableInts;


        [Params(
            // 10000 ... 1000000
        )]
        public int _count;

        public IntBenchmarks()
        {
            EnumerableInts = GetEnumerableInts();
        }


        private IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerableInts()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            {
                yield return 1;
            }
        }


        [Benchmark]
        public void ToArrayInt()
        {
            var r = EnumerableInts.ToArray();
        }


        [Benchmark]
        public void ToListInt()
        {
            var r = EnumerableInts.ToList();
        }

    }
```

Also, I know that memory allocates(there is the memory for a new array) when `_count` equals 530000. I'm very interested in why performance is better when the memory allocated. I have benchmarks for IEnumerable of class, struct, int string, only IEnumerable of int has such behavior

[image]

I checked it repeatedly

Memory tests:
[image]

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: I am surprised that `ToArray` is faster. I would bet that `ToList` would be faster because it involves less steps. ([Is it better to call ToList() or ToArray() in LINQ queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105990/is-it-better-to-call-tolist-or-toarray-in-linq-queries)). Did you tested it on .NET Framework too?

Comment: The implementations ```ToList``` are different in .net core and .net framework. I didn't test it on .net framework, but I know that ```ToList``` is better there, because of ```ToArray``` method call ```ToList``` internally. But .net core developers rewrote ```ToArray``` and it's faster now. @TheodorZoulias

Comment: I can see that there are also smaller pits starting at 130,000 and 260,000 items. It seems that the pits are following the resize pattern of the internal buffer (it is doubled in size when it becomes full).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I can't understand why? This is JIT trick maybe@TheodorZoulias

Comment: "The Art of Performance Measuring", the book of this [Benchmark] creator, is describing this 'List.Add' in the Pitfalls section. https://books.google.com/books?id=IXCfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=array.maxarraylength&source=bl&ots=P6WVcXmAQu&sig=ACfU3U1DH9PY4sAjYQEOTvlQaalzcF1UtA&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=array.maxarraylength&f=false

Comment: In .NET Core there is a specific optimization for enumerables created with `Enumerable.Range`. There is an internal class [`RangeIterator`](https://source.dot.net/System.Linq/System/Linq/Range.SpeedOpt.cs.html) that knows how to create arrays and lists as fast as possible. I have no idea what causes the pit though. It seems that there is a non-linear correlation between the size of the array and the time needed to allocate and initialize it. Larger arrays are allocated faster than smaller arrays, sometimes.

Comment: Could you provide an example when allocation larger arrays are faster than smaller, please?@TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 1):

The number of items in `EnumerableInts` is unknown. It's just an enumerable with an arbitrary number of items. Thus, when you call `ToArray()` the runtime must allocate an array with unknown size. Then it starts copying items from the enumerator. Once the array length has been reached, it will re-allocate a new array with twice the length. See [EnumerableHelpers.cs(76)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Common/src/System/Collections/Generic/EnumerableHelpers.cs#L76)

The larger number of items returned from the enumerator, the more temporary arrays will be allocated. The pits in your benchmark are caused by the **Garbage Collector**, collecting the temporary arrays that are no longer referenced.

Answer (score 0):

On a real IEnumerable, that cannnot be casted to anything else, what you enforce by using the yield return iterator method, `ToArray` is calling `ToList`, not because of `ToList` is faster, but it's more flexible, it's prepared to handle an unknown Count of Data. We have to avoid to enumerate the enumeration twice, what would happen if one would use the `Count()` extension, for example.

ToArray() would be faster - if you know the number of elements in advance. This would be the case if the source is an `ICollection` - it's actually the only idea of an `ICollection` to support this function - knowing the number of elements in Advance.

Your measurement is specific to pure Iterators (with yield return). If the IEnumerable is tested true, to be an `Array`, `IList` or `ICollection`, it's rather casted, and the native implementation `List.CopyTo` and `Array.CopyTo` is used. They do not enumerate the IEnumerable. 
Just to emphasize: **list.ToList(), and list.ToArray(), or int[].ToList(), or int[].ToArray(), would not show this behaviour**

I cannot explain possible differences of .NET/Core.

Comment: You described .net framework behavior. .net core ```ToArray``` method doesn't call ```ToList```. And my question why we have pit from 530 to 800 thousand. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I know, it's not an answer. But it was to much for a comment, and it's important to pronounce you are not measuring general behaviour, but only the case the really enumerates with MoveNext. I only checked the source code, and it doesn't look different to me.

Comment: Did you watch this [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs,783a052330e7d48d,references)?@Holger

Comment: @EvgeniyTerekhin Yes, and the https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Collections/Generic/EnumerableHelpers.cs,a8ba52888e4d53c1 EnumerableHelpers.ToArray, is exactly doing what I'm describing. (added another answer concerning the byte length). We are just joining forces of ideas.